# How to tackle bad editing?

Tags: discussion, editing

I posted this question,

"Why do characters from Marvel Universe have muscular physique most of the time?"

Which was edited to,

"Why do most comics characters have a muscular physique?"

Now I had specified characters from Marvel Universe. By editing the question, it broadens to other comics like Archies, Asterix & Obelix, Tintin and so on. Thus changing the meaning itself.

How did someone actually approved such worst editing?

Comment: If you don't like the edit, roll it back.

Comment: I did it. But what's the point if it is done 24 hrs later. Also, there might be chances that due to bad editing, it is marked as Duplicate or Put on hold...

Comment: IIRC, edits to closed questions bump the question to the re-open queue. If it's on-topic, it'll likely get re-opened. If not, come to meta or chat and we'll try to help you get it on-topic if we can.

Comment: I would have approved it. It's a pretty poor question in the first place so widening it doesn't actually make it any worse. As @phantom42 says, if you don't like an edit, just hit the rollback button.

Comment: The correct way to specify Marvel comics characters is to use the tag [tag:marvel-comics]. The shorter title is better; let the tags specify Marvel.

Answer (score 5):

Typically if the user's below a certain reputation their edit is put in a queue. If the edit doesn't seem up to standard it can be rejected for various reasons.

One of the primary reasons for rejecting an edit I'd that if changes there meaning too drastically.

In contrast, at 2k rep,  you don't need to *suggest* an edit;  it is in effect,  automatically approved.

Looking at the reviewer history,  someone with 2k+ rep edited the question,  so that is why it went through. I'd guess almost all edits by these trusted users don't need approval,  add they're fine.  For everything else there's the roll back system.

For more information on privileges,  see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).